# Counting number of words of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, symbolic-computation

I am considering this graph and semi-infinite walks on it. By $W_n$ denote the set of words of length $n$. I am trying to find out how many words of length $n$ there are, i.e. to find the cardinality of $W_n$.

For example, ABCD is a word of length $4$.

This seems to be rather tricky, at least I did not find an answer for general $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 4):

Let $A(n)$ be the number of words of length $n$ ending in $A$ and similarly for all the other letters.  You can write a set of coupled recurrences like $E(n)=K(n-1)+D(n-1)$, one for each letter.  You can encode this in a spreadsheet with $n$ in rows, the letters in columns, and the recurrence relations in the intersections.  $A(1)=1$ and the same for all the letters.  Write the recurrence into row $2$ and copy down.

Alternately you can think of a column vector with $A(n), B(n), \ldots N(n)$ as entries and a matrix you multiply on the left to increase $n$ to $n+1$.  If you can diagonalize the matrix you can find a closed form in terms of powers of the diagonal entries.

Comment: If I want, for example, know how many words of length 10 there are, then for example $$A(10)=G(9)=F(8)=D(7)+K(7)=C(6)+J(6)=B(5)+I(5)=A(4)+H(4)=G(3)+A(3)=F(2)+G(2)=E(1)+F(1)=2$$? And now I have to do the same for all the other letters. Thats cool but very much work. Maybe I should try the second approach. But I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Could you please explain your second approach a bit more? I do not understand what you mean. A closed form would be great.

Comment: They are really two ways of doing the same calculation.  It is a complicated diagram so it will be a lot of work.  The spreadsheet approach means you just need to write the equations once because you just reference the line above.  Copy down takes care of the rest.  It won't get a symbolic answer, but will give you the numeric answer without too much work.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with spreadsheet and copy down. I wrote down $A(n)=G(n-1), B(n)=A(n-1),...$ for all all letters

Comment: The matrix approach is the same equations.  The fifth row would have the computation for $E(n+1)$.  It would have $1$s in the fourth and eleventh columns representing the $E(n+1)=D(n)+K(n)$ equation.  It will be a $14 \times 14$ matrix with mostly zeros and a $1$ for each arrow in the diagram.  Each time you multiply the vector by it you get one more step.  Many matrices $M$ can be written  as $M=P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is diagonal.  Then you have $M^k=P^{-1}D^kP$ and finding the power of a diagonal matrix is easy.

Comment: The columns are A through N and the rows are $n$.  In row $1$ you put all $1$s as there is one string of length $1$ ending with each letter.  Then in row 2 under $E$ you put =up one, one left+up one, six left and similarly for all the other letters.  Then copy down and all the lines for $E$ will have the proper equation.

Comment: Is it possible to say exactly how many words of length $n$ there are which start and end at the same vertex?

Comment: It is possible.  I would look at the various cycles in the graph.  B can get back to B in $7$ steps by going around the top or in $10$ by going around the outside.  If you go around the outside you can add in another loop of $7$.  The number of $B...B$ words of length $17$ is then $2$, of length $24$ is $4$ and so on.